# Как каждый раз создавать новый список с другим названием при каждом срабатывании цикла for?

Tags: python

На вход программе подается число n, а затем n строк, содержащих целые числа в порядке возрастания. Из данных строк формируются списки чисел. Напишите программу, которая объединяет указанные списки в один отсортированный список с помощью функции quick_merge(), а затем выводит его.

**Sample Input 1:**

3

1 2 3 4

5 6 7

10 11 17

**Sample Output 1:**

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 17

я написал программу и не знаю как генерировать каждый раз новый список с другим названием, чтобы их записывать в созданную функцию при выводе ответа

```
def merge(*iters):
    for it in iters:
        yield from it

n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
  a = [int(j) for j in input().split()]


print(list(merge(a, b, c)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

лучше их всех положить в ещё один список

```
arr = []
for i in range(n):
  arr.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])


print(list(merge(*arr)))
```

чтобы убрать скобки по краям и запятые то пишите так

```
print(*list(merge(*arr)))
```

---

Если постараться то весь код можно уместить в одну строку

```
print(*sorted(sum([list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(int(input()))], [])))
```

Comment: выводит ответ в скобках, что сделать, чтобы без них и без запятых?

Answer (score 2):

просто используйте список списков

```
n = int(input())
data = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
```

если решать в лоб, то можно было бы сделать совсем простое решение

```
def merge():
    return sorted(sum([list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(int(input()))], []))
```

Comment: тогда и merge не нужен будет, тк уже все будет в `data`

Comment: @Андр в `data` будет массив массивов

Comment: @Danis и значит merge будет нужен, чтобы распаковать `data`?

Comment: дело в том что вам нужна быстрая сортировка, потому что в лоб можно сделать в 1 строчку, но будет медленнее